# JavaScript not drawing correctly from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am drawing circles from a specific place in a javascript array that has 3 dimensions (i think). I am drawing them using 2 levels of for loops, The first one handles the x coordinate for the circles and the second handles the y coordinates for the circles and then passes in the colour of the circle from the array (the array only contains their colour values) and passes them into the `Circle` function which just draws them from the x,y,colour and radius values. My code however only seems to draw one or doesn't seem the recognise the 3rd dimension in the array. The code is as follows:

```
//define the sequence of lights
var lightSequence = [[["red",'darkOrange','darkGreen','other'],["red",'darkOrange','darkGreen','other']],[['red',"orange",'darkGreen'],['red',"orange",'darkGreen']],[['darkRed','darkOrange',"green"],['darkRed','darkOrange',"green"]],[['darkRed',"orange",'darkGreen'],['darkRed',"orange",'darkGreen']]];
//draw all of the traffic lights from the array
for (var xMove = 0; xMove < lightSequence[i].length; xMove ++) {
    console.log(lightSequence[i][xMove]);
    for (var value = 0; value < lightSequence[i][xMove].length; value ++) {
        circle(xPos + (radius*(xMove * 2))+ (spacing * (xMove)), startY + (radius*(value * 2)) + (spacing * (value)), radius, lightSequence[i][xMove][value]);
        console.log([i][xMove][value]);
    }
}
```

The lights go in a sequence which is controlled by `i` so `[["red",'darkOrange','darkGreen','other'],["red",'darkOrange','darkGreen','other']]` is one single draw in the sequence and should draw 2 columns of 4 lights but all of the sections of the sequence seem to draw just one light (the last one in the array to be specific) but I don't know why. `xMove` controls the x Axis of the array and for drawing and `value` controls the y Axis of the array and for drawing the lights.

Comment: format to json and try

Comment: I am not programming in json and this will work in javascript so i would prefer it in javascript @Ray

Answer (score 0):

I managed to answer my own question in the end. The reason the code is not drawing all of the circles is because of line 8 that says `console.log([i][xMove][value]);` this should be `console.log(lightSequence[i][xMove][value]);` it was throwing up an error as before it wasnt reffering to a variable causing it to break out of the for statement and not continue the final code should be

```
//draw all of the traffic lights from the array
for (var xMove = 0; xMove < lightSequence[i].length; xMove ++) {
    console.log('lightSequence[i][xMove]: ' + lightSequence[i][xMove]);
    for (var value = 0; value < lightSequence[i][xMove].length; value ++) {
        circle(xPos + (radius*(xMove * 2))+ (spacing * (xMove)), startY + (radius*(value * 2)) + (spacing * (value)), radius, lightSequence[i][xMove][value]);
        console.log(lightSequence[i][xMove][value]);
    }
}
```